# What are these packets sent from my Tor client at irregular intervals during a download?

Tags: anonymity, fingerprinting

I am comparing two traffic instances using Wireshark: one using Tor and the other not using Tor. In both instances, the user requests the HTML document of a web page. In both instances I first filtered out the ACK packets, then I placed both traffic captures side by side and compared them.

[image: No Tor vs. Tor]

In the non-Tor capture file on the left, after an initial handshake protocol, there is an HTML request, followed by a continuous retrieval of the HTML document until complete.

In the Tor capture file on the right, although encrypted I can see a similar pattern of a continuous flow of packets from the entry relay to the user. However, there are times when the user sends a packet to the exit relay, which does not appear in the non-Tor capture file. An example of this is highlighted in the red border.

I did some reading of my own, specifically a research paper called Improved Website Fingerprinting on Tor, by Tao Wang and Ian Goldberg, where I read about SENDME cells, which are sent from the user to the Tor network every 50 cells as a form of flow control. However, looking at the capture files, the intervals in which I see extra packets is not always constant, so I’m assuming there may be other background traffic along with the SENDME cells.

[image: Irregularly sent packets]

What are these packets sent from my Tor client at irregular intervals during a download?

Comment: Why do you believe the packets are from or related to Tor and not some other process?

Comment: What else is in the packet? Is it part of Tor's TCP stream? You're looking at it from too far back...

Comment: @canonizingironize, I apologize for not specifying. I used tcpdump to look at the traffic, specifically on port 5000 which is the default onion router port, so it must be from Tor.

Comment: Tor is doing more than just a single circuit though, it keeps multiple circuits open at once. I'd recommend you approach it by looking at Tor with debugging logs to get a better idea of what Tor is doing at the time the packets are sent, if no one is able to give you an authoritative answer here.